# How do I determine whether type T is extending an interface?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a default value for a type that extends from `Entity`, or let the value be null otherwise. This is my (pseudo)code:

```
export interface Entity {
    id: number;
    // ...
}

@Component({})
export class EpicComponent<T> {
  @Input() data: T[] | null = null;
  @Input() identifier: keyof T | null = T is of type Entity ? 'id' : null; // <--
}
```

When `T` is an `Entity`, I'm sure it has an `id`, so I want the `identifier` to be the `id` by default. However, for some other types I might need another property as `identifier`. Is this possible in TypeScript? Or perhaps by doing this in a different way? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Interfaces in TypeScript do not exist at runtime, and you're writing the runtime code. The easiest way to do what you're trying to would be setting the `identifier` to `"id"` if such property exists on the first element of `data` when it's bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the interface to check inheritance, since interfaces are not compiled to JS. But you can use type guards to safely check duck typing like `isEntity` function is doing.

Does something like this works for you?

```
export interface Entity {
  id: number;
  // ...
}

function isEntity(o: any): o is Entity {
  return (o as Entity)?.id != null;
}

@Component({})
export class EpicComponent<T> {
@Input() data: T[] | null = null;
@Input() identifier: keyof T | null = null;

ngOnInit() {
  if(isEntity(this.data?.[0])) {
    this.identifier = 'id' as keyof T;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Elegante and pure

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this does indeed work. `as keyof T` however accepts anything you put in the string.